# Need to add an interactive 3D model to my otherwise non-3D app

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

As briefly as I can; are there any frameworks available that I can drop into an iPad app I'm working on, along with a 3D model, and allow me to add a view that will present the model in an interactive format?
Model needs to be rotatable, and ideally I would like to be able to add interactive points on to the model that pop up modal views when tapped.

I have never worked with 3D before in any respect so I'm coming at that part as a complete novice. The 3D model is being supplied to me and will be available in "various formats". The rest of the app is pure Objective-C in which I'm proficient enough.

I have Googled and Googled and have come up with nothing so far.

Failing there being any drop-in frameworks, how much of a challenge is it likely to be to get myself up to speed with what I would need to know? Are there any good starting points to expand my knowledge here?

Comment: [SceneKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/SceneKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Comment: My question didn't clarify this fully before, but it's an iPad app. From what I can tell SceneKit is OS X only...

Comment: In fact if you just Google SceneKit, you'll see more resources on iOS SceneKit than OS X SceneKit http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.hk/2012/08/an-introduction-to-scenekit.html

Comment: Quote from that article "Unfortunately, as of right now, SceneKit is a Mac-only technology. I've seen been no evidence yet that SceneKit will be included in iOS 6. It's still possible, but I'm not holding my breath. If not, well… fingers crossed for iOS 7."

Comment: Currently learning open Gl myself. Its a big undertaking, but a good skill to have. I don't know if this link will be any help? http://www.ogre3d.org/about

Answer (score 1):

3D is a complex matter, if you don't see your future dealing with it on a regular basis I wouldn't recommend writing your own solutions for it.

The closest you can find to a drag and drop framework would be the SDK of the iPhone / iPad GPU's manufacturer. It's pretty easy to use.

[PowerVR SDK Download](http://www.imgtec.com/PowerVR/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp)

After a free registration on their website, you can download the SDK that contains lots of samples with source code. Their framework displays 3D models in their own POD format, which is of course heavily optimized for the iOS devices. Ask your 3D model provider to give you the models in POD format (you can find POD converters / exporters for Maya etc. on PowerVR's website as well).